# Find number with fixed start digits

Tags: php, regex, string, strpos

I'm trying to print out a line, when I find a 10 or 11 digit number starting with `0123` inside the line.

The `$line` will contains lots of data, all I'm interested in is checking the line and seeing if there is a number starting with `0123` and is 10 or 11 digits long.  I don't care where it is in the line.

My current code looks like this:

```
$lines = file('test.txt');

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (strpos($line,'0123?????'))
        echo "$line<br/>";
}
```

I've found out that `strpos()` doesn't support wildcards. So is there any way around this so `strpos()` accepts wildcards or do I need to do this in another way?

Comment: Take a look at `preg_match()`. And use https://regex101.com to construct the regex.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This seems to work `0123\d{6,7}\b`

Comment: Yup you got it! Note that since you don't have `\b` at the start your regex could also match `7890123...`.

Comment: You can self-answer your question if you want, since you now figured it out yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer :)

Comment: @Rizier123 If you post it as an answer I'll accept it as you've helped and I've learn something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are some function to do it in a row, but old school:

**1. Check if the string has the prefix `0123`:**

```
substr($line, 0, 4 ) === "0123"
```

**2. Get the string count:**

```
strlen($line) >= 10
```

and so:

```
$lines = file('test.txt');
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $stringCount = strlen($line);
    if (substr($line, 0, 4 ) === "0123" && ($stringCount == 10 || $stringCount == 11))
    echo "$line<br/>";
}
```

EDIT:

```
$pos = strpos($lines, '0123');

if ($pos) {
    $diff = $stringCount - $pos
    if($diff == 10 || $diff == 11) {
        echo "$line<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks the line may contain 100's of characters. I want to check if a match exists any where in the line

Answer (score 0):

https://3v4l.org/tLH7B

```
foreach($lines as $line){
    $len = strlen($line);
    if(($len==10||$len==11)&&"0123"===substr($line, 0, 4))
        echo "valid: $line \n";
}
```

what do you need a wildcard for?

Comment: thanks the line may contain 100's of characters. I want to check if a match exists any where in the line

Comment: your question says the line has to be 10 or 11 chars. you are contradicting yourself. please clarify. @Tom